# Correlating beta-lactamase expression to absorbance

Tags: biochemistry, homework, bacteriology, enzymes

> When penicillin-resistant bacteria are grown in liquid culture media,
>   β-lactamase is secreted into the medium. The supernatant of such a medium can be assayed for β-lactamase activity. Culture supernatants 
>   different organisms , which are suspected to be penicillin-resistant,
>   were obtained and were assayed for β-lactamase activity. The corresponding absorbance value were measured at a certain wavelength.

Let us assume that supernatant from organism 1's culture had absorbance value X and 2 had absorbance value Y.

My question : If X>Y, does that mean that more β-lactamase was being produced by organism 1 ?

Comment: How does this beta-lactamase assay work? If it works in a way that more secreted enzyme metabolizes more substrate resulting in more absorbance, than yes.

Comment: @chris It's been treated with an inhibitor of B-lactamase.

Comment: The supernatant is treated with a b-lactamase inhibitor? And what happens then? Or does the inhibitor change its color due to the inhibition?

Comment: @chris Yes the color becomes yellow. What would happen to the absorbance then ?

Comment: Ok, then more b-lactamase means more inhibitor binding and this results in more color development leading to a higher absorption. So higher absorption means more b-lactamase in the supernatant.

Comment: Hi @Chris You have answered my question in the comments. Do you want to write an answer ?

Comment: I can do that later today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the β-lactamase test, an inhibitor of β-lactamase is added to a sample of the culture medium. The inhibitor binds to the enzyme and changes its color, which is in direct correlation to the concentration of the β-lactamase. More β-lactamase means more inhibitor binding and this results in more color development leading to a higher absorption. So higher absorption means more β-lactamase in the supernatant.